# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was ''

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, authentication

I have a website which trying to connect webservice. That webservice enabled with single sign on authentication. My website also enabled with SSO authentication.

From my webservice i have to connect that webservice with SSO credentials. So i used below configuration and i can able to connect and get data from that webservice. So it is working on my local machine. After i deployed this code to Dev server then i am getting this error "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was ''."

Please help me... Thanks in advance...

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume, your machine and the server are in the same domain, right?

In IIS, what are the Authentication methods enabled to the webservice and website? You have to enable ONLY Windows Authentication...

PS.: Sorry, i am don't speak english very well :)

Comment: Yes both are in same domain only and it enabled with windows authentication.